# Erlang how can I see application output via JCL on detached erl?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I firstly start a node_a on detached mode, then start a node_b console and use JCL(Ctrl+G) to connect to node_a, then I use application:start/1 to start an application. then I can't see every io:format output in the application. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `io:format` use a logging solution like [lager](https://github.com/basho/lager) and do a `tail -f console.log` to see updated to the STDOUT output. If I recall correctly STDOUT is send to `/dev/null` by default on a detached node (if you don't use a logging solution like lager).

If you want to work with the remote shell, and see direct output, you could use `io:fwrite(user,"the result is ~w\n",[X])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the erlang function group_leader(Group_leader,Pid) for that. here a small example:

In one console I run the function:

```
ploop(I) ->
  io:format("mess num ~p, group_leader is ~p~n",[I,group_leader()]),
  receive
    stop -> io:format("bye bye~n"); 
    {group,P,F} ->
      group_leader(P,self()),
      F ! group_changed,
      ploop(0)
  after 5000 ->
    ploop(I+1)
  end.
```

in the second console after connect to a remote shell, i send the message:

```
PD ! {group,group_leader(),self()}.
```

where PD is the pid of the process ploop, and that's it. But this must be done for all the processes you want to catch the io:format. You may do this using the result of processes(), but I did not verify it.

Comment: this may do, but not a good way in practice. i'm now writing my logs into file.

Comment: I personally use gen_event and attach different logger on demand, depending on what I am looking for (simple console log, ets, graphical interface...), but my answer works and does what you were asking :o) BTW I didn't check what happens to the spied process when you close the remote console.